# How to save edited data record in access form as a new record?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am facing a little issue now. My issue is that currently when i made edit to the current record in my subform and click on "update" it will overwrite my previous record which i do not want. 
Instead, I would like to add my edited data record from the subform and insert it into the subform as a new record with the same PO number as the one that i am editing.

Below are my code:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'when we click on button Add there are two options
    '1. for insert
    '2. for update
If Me.txtID.Tag & "" = "" Then
    'this is for insert new
    'add data to table
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO mxd " & _ 
    "(ID,Fabrication,Width,FinishedGoods,Colour, " & _
    "LabDipCode,GrossWeight,NettWeight, " & _
    "Lbs,Loss,Yds,Remarks,POType,ComboName,GroundColour)" & _
    " VALUES(" & Me.txtID & ",'" & Me.txtFabrication & "','" & _
    Me.txtWidth & "','" & Me.txtFinishedGood & "','" & _
    Me.txtColour & "','" & Me.txtLabDipCode & "','" & _
    Me.txtGrossweight & "','" & _ Me.txtNettweight & "','" & _
    Me.txtLbs & "','" & Me.txtLoss & "','" & _ Me.txtYds & "','" & _
    Me.txtRemarks & "','" & Me.cboPoType "','" & _
    Me.txtGroundColour & "','" & Me.txtComboName & "')"
Else
    'otherwise (Tag of txtID store the id of student to be modified)
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE mxd " & _
    " SET ID = " & Me.txtID & _
    ", Fabrication = '" & Me.txtFabrication & "'" & _
    ", Width = '" & Me.txtWidth & "'" & _
    ", FinishedGoods = '" & Me.txtFinishedGood & "'" & _
    ", Colour = '" & Me.txtColour & "'" & _
    ", LabDipCode = '" & Me.txtLabDipCode & "'" & _
    ", GrossWeight = '" & Me.txtGrossweight & "'" & _
    ", NettWeight = '" & Me.txtNettweight & "'" & _
    ", LBS = '" & Me.txtLbs & "'" & _
    ", Loss = '" & Me.txtLoss & "'" & _
    ", Yds = '" & Me.txtYds & "'" & _
    ", Remarks = '" & Me.txtRemarks & "'" & _
    ", POType = '" & Me.cboPoType & "'" & _
    ", ComboName = '" & Me.txtComboName & "'" & _
    ", GroundColour = '" & Me.txtGroundColour & "'" & _
    " WHERE ID = " & Me.txtID.Tag

    End If

    'clear form
    cmdClear_Click
    'refresh data in list on form
    FormMxdSub.Form.Requery


End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
    Me.txtID = ""
    Me.txtFabrication = ""
    Me.txtWidth = ""
    Me.txtFinishedGood = ""
    Me.txtColour = ""
    Me.txtLabDipCode = ""
    Me.txtGrossweight = ""
    Me.txtNettweight = ""
    Me.txtLbs = ""
    Me.txtLoss = ""
    Me.txtYds = ""
    Me.txtRemarks = ""
    Me.cboPoType = ""
    Me.txtKeywords = ""
    Me.txtComboName = ""
    Me.txtGroundColour = ""

    'focus on ID text box
    Me.txtID.SetFocus

    'set button edit to enable
    Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True
    'change caption of button add to Add
    Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Add"
    'clear tag on txtID for reset new
    Me.txtID.Tag = ""

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    'delete record
    'check existing selected record
    If Not (Me.FormMxdSub.Form.Recordset.EOF And 
        Me.FormMxdSub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        'confirm delete
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            'delete now
            CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM mxd " & _
            "where ID = " & Me.FormMxdSub.Form.Recordset.Fields("ID")
            'refresh data in list
            Me.FormMxdSub.Form.Requery
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
    'check whether there is exists data in list
    If Not (Me.FormMxdSub.Form.Recordset.EOF And 
        Me.FormMxdSub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        'get data to text box control
        With Me.FormMxdSub.Form.Recordset
            Me.txtID = .Fields("ID")
            Me.txtFabrication = .Fields("Fabrication")
            Me.txtWidth = .Fields("Width")
            Me.txtFinishedGood = .Fields("FinishedGoods")
            Me.txtColour = .Fields("Colour")
            Me.txtLabDipCode = .Fields("LabDipCode")
            Me.txtGrossweight = .Fields("GrossWeight")
            Me.txtNettweight = .Fields("NettWeight")
            Me.txtLbs = .Fields("Lbs")
            Me.txtLoss = .Fields("Loss")
            Me.txtYds = .Fields("Yds")
            Me.txtRemarks = .Fields("Remarks")
            Me.cboPoType = .Fields("POType")
            Me.txtComboName = .Fields("ComboName")
            Me.txtGroundColour = .Fields("GroundColour")
            'store id of student in Tag of txtID in case id is modified
            Me.txtID.Tag = .Fields("ID")
                'change caption of button add to update
            'Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Update"
            'disable button edit
            Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = False
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *RecordsetClone* to create a dupe of the current record. Much faster and cleaner and no Tag is needed:

```
Private Sub btnCopy_Click()

  Dim rstSource   As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rstInsert   As DAO.Recordset
  Dim fld         As DAO.Field

  If Me.NewRecord = True Then Exit Sub

  Set rstInsert = Me.RecordsetClone
  Set rstSource = rstInsert.Clone
  With rstSource
    If .RecordCount > 0 Then
      ' Go to the current record.
      .Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
      With rstInsert
        .AddNew
          For Each fld In rstSource.Fields
            With fld
              If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
              ElseIf .Name = "SomeFieldToExclude" Then
                ' Leave field blank.
              ElseIf .Name = "SomeOtherFieldToExclude" Then
                ' Leave field blank.
              Else
                ' Copy field content.
                rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = .Value
              End If
            End With
          Next
        .Update
        ' Go to the new record and sync form.
        .MoveLast
        Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
        .Close
      End With
    End If
    .Close
  End With

  Set rstInsert = Nothing
  Set rstSource = Nothing

End Sub
```

Of course, if you place the button on the main form, replace in the code `Me` with a reference to the subform: `Me!NameOfYourSubformControl.Form`

Comment: Thankyou for your reply! With this code above, i am able to add a new row of data that i have finished editing?

Comment: Not before it is saved. So copy it before you start editing.